# Highlight content on website with Tab key navigation for accessibility

Tags: css, wordpress

I built a website for an initiative at my school with Wordpress and an external theme(Stockholm from Qode Interactive). However in order for the the website to be published by school, it has to be compliant with accessibilty features. Currently Tab key navigation works but without highlighting the content, so ther eis no cisual feedback for the user to know what content is selected.

I wonder if this can be achieved with simple CSS comand?

I couldn't get help from wordpress as this is and external theme issue which is difficult to get support from thr developer. I can see at the lower left corner that content is selected when the Tab key is pressed.